# TextBox entry Validation based on SQL data object

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

Im validating user entered text, entered into a textbox, to filter out non-numbers,and then compare >=  / < to an object pulled from a database. 
My issue is happening in 2 places though it may be just 1 issue. I have a conversion of a data table item into a string, then into an int. This int is then passed into a series of if /else statements that should validate the users input. After stepping through the program it hits my conversion statement appears to do the conversion, then proceeds to skip my if /else statements.

```
   int classRPM;
        int fanRPM;
        string actualdata = string.Empty;
        char[] entereddata = txfanrpm.Text.ToCharArray();
        foreach (char aChar in entereddata.AsEnumerable())
        {
            if (Char.IsDigit(aChar))
            {
                actualdata = actualdata + aChar;

                using (Fanrpm ds = new Fanrpm(cbdesigntype.SelectedValue.ToString(), cbfansize.SelectedValue.ToString(), cbfanclass.SelectedValue.ToString()))
                {
                    DataTable dt = ds.dataset.Tables[0];
                    classRPM = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0].Field<string>("ClassRPM"));

                   // MessageBox.Show(aChar.ToString());
                    fanRPM = Convert.ToInt32(actualdata);
                    if (fanRPM >= classRPM)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("hi");
                    }
                    else if (fanRPM < classRPM)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Hide");
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(aChar + " is not numeric");
                actualdata.Replace(aChar, ' ');
                actualdata.Trim();
            }
        }
        txfanrpm.Text = actualdata;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "proceeds to skip my if /else statements."?

Comment: as in the program does not step through it to either show the messagebox of hi or hide. IT does do the first and last if/else as any non number will prompt the * is not numeric else.

Comment: Do you have this code wrapped in an exception handler? Are you stepping through the code? Did you see a message when you had your `MessageBox.Show(aChar.ToString());` code there?

Comment: Use the debugger. Set a breakpoint on the for line (F9) then step through your code with F10. Be sure to have checked DEBUG->Exceptions->Common Language Runtime Exceptions for User Unhandled. When the error hits you should be able to see the reason in exception message property.

Comment: That piece of code (MessageBox.Show(aChar.ToString())) was a mistake that it got uncommented, while it was uncommented it did nothing and was also skiped,  there is no error handling yet.

Comment: No errors the program just continues to run after the classrpm= covert line, classrpm never gets filled with a value, so i double checked my select statement and it works perfecting in sqlserver with provided data, and can verifiy that it is getting the correct data from the selectedvalue's. 
Ive had alot of trouble getting single items from datatables.

Comment: What is the datatype of the database field ClassRPM? If you check the contents of `dt.Rows[0].Field<string>("ClassRPM")` what is its value? If you press F10 in the debugger when the highlight is over the Convert line, the next code executed is the line that reads the fanRPM value?

Comment: in the database itself the classrpm is a float, as its a number. pressing f10 pulls the program back up it doesn't ever step through anything else in this method and moves on to my next comboboxselected event.

Comment: So it is basically wrong to get it as a string and then try to convert to an integer. If it is a float perhaps it contains also the decimal separator. Try with `float ClassRPM = dt.Rows[0].Field<float>("ClassRPM");` Probably the rest of the code needs some adjusting

Comment: im admin to the database i could change the type to int or anything else if that would simplify things.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58833/discussion-between-steve-and-himarm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the comments above I think you could change your code in this way

```
// If the reading from the database gives always the same value is not correct to 
// exexute this code inside the foreach. Just do it one time here and go on....

float classRPM = 0.0f;
using (Fanrpm ds = new Fanrpm(cbdesigntype.SelectedValue.ToString(),
                              cbfansize.SelectedValue.ToString(), 
                              cbfanclass.SelectedValue.ToString()))
{
     DataTable dt = ds.dataset.Tables[0];
     classRPM = dt.Rows[0].Field<float>("ClassRPM");
}

float fanRPM;
string actualdata = string.Empty;

// No need to use AsEnumerable.... 
// And also this code could be easily replaced by single line float.TryParse 
// if you don't need to show a message box for every wrong char....
foreach (char aChar in txfanrpm.Text.ToCharArray())
{
    if (Char.IsDigit(aChar))
        actualdata = actualdata + aChar;
    else
        MessageBox.Show(aChar + " is not numeric");
}
// Now you could start your comparisons....
fanRPM = Convert.ToSingle(actualdata);
if (fanRPM >= classRPM)
   MessageBox.Show("hi");
else
   MessageBox.Show("Hide");
```